# Matplotlib subplots column wrap

Tags: python, matplotlib

Does Matplotlib have a built-in column wrap method?

The following image shows an analogous method in Seaborn's [catplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#).

[image: Screenshot of Seaborn col_wrap usage in the catplot documentation.]

#### Purpose...

I have a function that plots *N* images with `plt.imshow()`. The number of images can varies, from about 20 to 50. I am using subplots to tile them, and would like to automate the number of 'rows' by using a wrapping function such as the one mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's built-in support for a column wrapper in matplotlib.

In fact, if you look at the Seaborn source code for FacetGrid, you can see that the author uses a simple calculation based on the col_wrap parameter to build the subplot layout.

```
if col_wrap is not None:
  if row is not None:
      err = "Cannot use `row` and `col_wrap` together."
      raise ValueError(err)
  ncol = col_wrap
  nrow = int(np.ceil(len(col_names) / col_wrap))
```

https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/axisgrid.py#L418

Comment: thank you for pointing out the source code. I wonder if the functionality has been considered by Matplotlib developers